# Help with C# documentation

Tags: c#, .net, documentation

I'm an iOS dev trying to write a small client app in C#.

I'm having trouble with the MSDN documentation. What do I search for on the MSDN website to differentiate what I want from all of the ASP and web related results? (I'm trying to pop up message box.)

Is there a name of the desktop .NET technologies that I don't know about that differentiates from "web" .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look for the [`System.Windows.Forms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.aspx) namespace for winforms.

Or, if using WPF, for [`Windows Presentation Foundation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx).

Both are the non-web platforms for windows GUI applications.

Answer (score 1):

You could try "Windows Forms in the .NET Framework" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96bef039.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MSDNSTART)&rd=true

For your specific question, try "How to: Display Message Boxes" - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tt9e94f(v=VS.80).aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MSDNSTART)&rd=true

This page is a good source to find areas in the .NET docs by topic - Quick Technology Finder (.NET Framework) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63bf39c2.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MSDNSTART)&rd=true